# Issue in saving image to desktop

Tags: java, image, file-io

Trying to save a image from [this](http://ramp.sdr.co.za/zp-core/i.php?a=1402NYFW/NicholasK&i=1402_NYFW_1005_NicholasK.JPG&w=387&h=580&cw=&ch=&q=92&wmk=!) URL which gets transformed to a image. Looks like I am missing something, the image is not getting saved on the desktop

```
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.File;
import java.net.URL;
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;

public class Image {

    public static void main(String[] args) {


        BufferedImage image = null;
        try {
            String url = "http://ramp.sdr.co.za/zp-core/i.php?a=1402NYFW/NicholasK&i=1402_NYFW_1005_NicholasK.JPG&w=387&h=580&cw=&ch=&q=92&wmk=!";

            String imgPath = null;
            imgPath = "C:/temp" + "a" + "";
            URL imageUrl = new URL(url);
            image = ImageIO.read(imageUrl);
            if (image != null) {
                System.out.println("in here");
                File file = new File(imgPath);
                ImageIO.write(image, "jpg", file);
            }

        } catch (Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: So nothing gets saved and no exceptions are thrown? Your imgPath does not look good. It is being written to the root directory, not a temp directory and has no .jpg extension give to it.

Comment: You are not writing to the desktop, why would it get saved there?

Comment: Yep, I agree with @MartinDinov, and it looks like some careless mistakes are happening here.

Comment: is the image being saved in the source folder?

Comment: @La-comadreja: look at his code. He's saving it directly to the C drive, not even to a folder. It's in a file named `C:/tempa`. No jpg extension, no folder.

Answer (score 2):

You may not have appropriate user privileges to write to "C:/tempa".  Event if you decided to use "c:/temp", the folder may not exist and you may not have the required privileges to either create it or write to it.

You could use `System.getProperties("user.home")`, which will return the current users home directory, which is more likely to allow you to write to it

```
String imgPath = System.getProperties("user.home") + "/a image.jpg";
File file = new File(imgPath);
ImageIO.write(image, "jpg", file);
```

I'd also add a `else` statement to your `if` statement so you can see when the image didn't load